# SikuliLibrary - RobotFramework OCR can't read text ['--- no text ---']

Tags: ocr, robotframework

I am using SikuliLibrary with Robot Framework. OCR is configured correctly.
 'Set Ocr Text Read' & 'Get Text' is ok. But after running script no text is read.
'--- no text ---'
I have started Sikuli server also. Can any one help me pls.
Thanks in advance.
Error report from RIDE log_ 
[error] TextRecognizer: init: export tessdata not possible - run setup with option 3
[error] TextRecognizer not working: tessdata stuff not available at:
C:\Users\jklkumarra\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\SikulixTesseract\tessdata
[error] text: text recognition is now switched off
20161207 10:59:47.881 :  INFO : ${username_get} = --- no text ---
20161207 10:59:47.885 :  FAIL : '--- no text ---' does not contain 'Rahman'
Ending test:   catiav6-Lokman.Catiav6 Test Demo.Login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was _ 
TextRecognizer not working: tessdata stuff not available at:
C:\Users\jklkumarra\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\SikulixTesseract\tessdata
I have just added tessdata stuff into above directory & solved my problem.